# Multiprocessing + Flask OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use / OSError: [Errno 38] Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, flask, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to build a Flask app that runs a function that eventually utilizes the multiprocessing library.

```
import time
from flask import Flask, request

import multiprocessing as mp

app = Flask(__name__)

def proc():
    time.sleep(10)

@app.route('/greeting')
def greeting():
    p = mp.Process(target=proc, args=())
    p.start()
    return ('Hello there')

app.run(port=8000)
```

The problem occurs when I go to `http://localhost:8000/greeting` and get the following error trying to call `p.start()`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/michaelequi/Github/drlm/apps/mp_flask.py", line 18, in <module>
    app.run(port=8000)
  File "/Users/michaelequi/Github/drlm/venv/drlm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 920, in run
    run_simple(t.cast(str, host), port, self, **options)
  File "/Users/michaelequi/Github/drlm/venv/drlm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1010, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/Users/michaelequi/Github/drlm/venv/drlm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 950, in inner
    srv = make_server(
  File "/Users/michaelequi/Github/drlm/venv/drlm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 782, in make_server
    return ThreadedWSGIServer(
  File "/Users/michaelequi/Github/drlm/venv/drlm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 688, in __init__
    super().__init__(server_address, handler)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

If I change the code such that debug=True (`app.run(port=8000, debug=True)`) I get a different error!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/michaelequi/Github/drlm/venv/drlm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 950, in inner
    srv = make_server(
  File "/Users/michaelequi/Github/drlm/venv/drlm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 782, in make_server
    return ThreadedWSGIServer(
  File "/Users/michaelequi/Github/drlm/venv/drlm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 676, in __init__
    real_sock = socket.fromfd(fd, self.address_family, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 545, in fromfd
    return socket(family, type, proto, nfd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 232, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 38] Socket operation on non-socket
```

This occurs no matter what port I run the flask server on. Anyone know what may be causing this and how to fix it? I am using Python 3.9.9 on MacOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`app.run(port=8000)`

with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000)
```

When using multiprocessing, anything that is "top level" gets run in every thread.  So both your main thread and the thread you're creating try to open port 8000

Comment: Hmm, interesting. This seems to fix it. Thanks! Any chance you could explain a bit more as to why this works. I understand that what is in the top level gets run in every thread but why does app.run get called even when the multiprocessing stuff happens in a totally different file?

Comment: When start a new process, it has to re-read all of your code. Here, it has to re-read your file just to know the definition of `proc()` which you've asked it to call.  And it sees `app.run()` and assumes it needs to call that.  With multiprocessing, it is important to separate out the code that only needs to be run by the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling us:

```
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

This is probably because something else is using the same port, or even an instance of this same program.

Comment: It seems to be doing this all within the program (If kill any other python programs and just run this script the issue is still present). My guess is that the multiprocessing module is trying to use the same port as flask and no matter what I change the port that flask uses, the multiprocessing module tries to use the same one. Thats only a guess and I am not sure how to fix it but I am 100% sure it is not because two different python scripts are running and utilizing the same port.

Comment: Does it run if you remove the multiprocessing lines, and just leave `return ('Hello there')` ?

Comment: Yes, the error is specifically when I start the process with the line p.start()